# Probation review. what to expect and talk about

Tags: united-kingdom, performance-reviews, probation

I haven't had performance review in my career and it might seem odd but I feel danger, my manager is based in another city and we are in another. He is coming for our meeting. I know I had issues and i might get laid off today but do I get a chance to talk of why I am so slow or why I had trouble communicating or I do that in a appeal (If I am allowed to appeal the decision)?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, ask yourself whether you really need/want this job. Can you see yourself working to the same standards/performance as the rest of the team currently does?

Let your manager lead the discussion the way that he wants to - don't immediately start talking about how badly you've been doing as he might have his own expectations about your initial performance.

Think about the reasons about why you feel you're under-performing and think about proposals to help that performance increase going forwards.

It's OK to ask for help - you don't have to swim by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience of working in the UK, there are 3 possible outcomes from the review:

1. You pass and therefore your contract may change (e.g. longer notice period). Note that statutory employment rights don't come into effect until 2 years' of continuous employment
2. The probation period is extended. this is often supported with a Performance Improvement Plan (PiP). There are plenty of questions on the site if that is the category you end up falling into
3. You are let go. If this happens, then the employer has to pay you for your notice period. A good employer will have signaled beforehand that this may be a possibility

In the review itself, your manager is likely to discuss your performance against your objectives and rate you on a scale provided by HR.

Unfortunately, many new starters are not inducted on the review process and how to succeed, but I would be prepared with some concrete examples of how you have performed well and become comfortable with the company culture. If your manager raises aspects for you to improve, remain neutral and suggest ways to improve.

Best of luck. Please let us know how it goes!